# Running Blackberry 10 simulator on a mac

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to find a way to run the blackberry 10 simulator on a mac. Apparently virtual box wont work, so is there any free alternative? Since `vmware 5` is not available for Mac, only `vmware fusion(53 euro)`, I find it strange since the required software is free on `Windows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not seem to be possible, after extensive research it seems that the correct software needs to be bought. The best solution would obviously be to own a real device.